# What does the word "step" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does the word "step" mean "dance"? Is in "dance music"

Urban Dictionary def [Oochie Wally](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Oochie%20Wally)

> Is an urban **step song** sang by young urban girls:

"Step" Merriam Webster def:
"Dance"
*Joyfully along the contra lines, the dancers held hands, listened to the caller, and stepped to the music*

Comment: It should be _sung by_, not _sang_!

Comment: Your question is valid, but please be aware that Urban Dictionary is a terrible resource.  It is not a real dictionary and it is full of poorly written entries, private jokes, and general nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A step song is a song designed for step dancing. It has rhythmic patterns and a melody that go well together with this dance genre.

A step dance is [a dance in which steps are emphasized rather than gesture or posture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/step%20dance).

In your second sentence, step is used as a verb. To step means [to move with measured steps, as in a dance](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/step), to dance.